# segmentation fault in findcontours opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault, contour

I am trying to detect a ball and draw boundaries to it. It shows the error

```
segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The mistake is somewhere here,

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

   Mat itt = Mat::zeros( imgThresholded.size(), CV_8UC1 );
itt = imgThresholded*255;

Canny( itt ,itt, 10, 30, 3 );
vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly( contours.size() );
vector<Point2f>center( contours.size() );
vector<float>radius( contours.size() );
vector<Rect> boundRect( contours.size() );
imshow("canny", itt);
//CIRCLE HOUGH
//vector<Vec3f> circles;
findContours( itt, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );
for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
     {
         Scalar color = Scalar(255,255,255);

       if( contours[i].size() > points )
       {approxPolyDP( Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true );
      boundRect[i] = boundingRect( Mat(contours_poly[i]) );
       minEnclosingCircle( (Mat)contours_poly[i], center[i], radius[i] );
       circle( imgOriginal, center[i], (int)radius[i],color, 2, 8, 0 );
     }
     }
```

I am not able to understand where there is segfault.

Comment: *I am not able to understand where there is segfault.*  -- So you weren't ready to debug your application if there was an issue?  What line of code produces the segmentation fault?

Comment: The for condition had the problem, when commented there was no problem. And also, without commentting it.. it works but when I bring the ball to the screen, the code just exits and shows this segfault. ie; if there is any thing getting detected, the code stops. Not able to understand where the problem is

Comment: If `findCountours` takes `contours` by reference, and in that function, it removes or adds items to the `countours` vector, then your other vectors have not been resized appropriately.

Comment: You're probably using debug libs in release, or viceversa. Or mixing x86 and x64 libs. Or libs compiled with a different compiler

Comment: First find contours and then declare center, radius and other parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare other vectors after findContours as shown below. For further reference you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36138094/segmentation-fault-in-findcontours/36138581#36138581). Hope this resolves you error. I have faced the same error and got the solution for this in the link I have mentioned.

```
findContours( itt, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );
vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly( contours.size() );
vector<Point2f>center( contours.size() );
vector<float>radius( contours.size() );
vector<Rect> boundRect( contours.size() );
```

Answer (score 1):

You first do
vector boundRect( contours.size() );
Here, contours is still empty.
Then you call findContours, which calculates and sets the size of contours,
then you try to directly write it to boundRect[i].

Just call boundRect.push_back(boundingRect( Mat(contours_poly[i]) ) ); instead, then you should be fine.

If you are doing prototypical code, it is generally better for debugging to use boundRect.at(i) = ..., because this will give you an understandable error like "out of range".